# How to check when the phone was turned on? (4.4 kitkat)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I turned my phone on today and there's something weird there. I would like to check if someone turned it on recently. Like, computer booting log. How can I do it?

Comment: AFAIK there is no protocol of that – unless you've setup something yourself.